# How to execute a gradle task at the end of the task graph?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How do I execute a task at the end of the task graph.

The task

```
task lastTask{
        //do something
}
```

should be executed at the end of the task graph.

Is it enough to do the following?

```
project.taskgraph.whenReady{
    lastTask
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this.

```
dependsOn
```

and

```
finalizedBy
```

The first will be used if there is a relationship between the tasks in which the second task is depending on the first. The latter might be used if the task before is of some kind of helper.
It is also explained [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/when-should-one-use-dependson-and-when-finalizedby/4066).

Both ways can be used in combination with the former last task, of the task graph.

Answer (score 1):

The task graph is resolved in Gradle's configuration phase. You can't execute a task in the configuration phase, you can only execute tasks in the execution phase.

See [build lifecycle phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)

Perhaps you want your task to always execute before any other task? In which case you could do

```
task myTask {
    doLast { ... }
}
tasks.all { Task t ->
    if (t != myTask) {
        t.dependsOn myTask       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the help @lance-java, but it is not was I was looking for. It looks like 'finalizedBy' would do the job. I just need to declare it for the former last task of the graph.